# square-connect v2 - how are sales metrics defined / calculated?

Tags: square-connect

Is there somewhere in the square documentation where terms like "Gross Sales", "Net Sales", etc are defined *precisely*, along with how the taxes are calculated?

Looking at the sales reports it's totally unclear how these numbers are produced.

I've been trying to re-create the sales summary report with the `/ListTransactions` endpoint but it's impossible without this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the v2 ListTransactions endpoint does not break down transaction amounts in such a way that it's straightforward to recreate the Square dashboard's sales summary report. However, the v1 [List Payments](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#get-payments) endpoint *does*. [This section](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#payments) of the v1 documentation describes the monetary fields of a `Payment` object returned by v1.

Additionally, [this PHP code sample](https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/master/connect-examples/v1/php/payments-report.php) demonstrates generating something very similar to the dashboard sales summary report using v1 endpoints. The sample is also available in a few other languages.

Comment: is there a timeline for deprecating the v1 api?